# Making sure that the page was requested by specific program

Tags: php, web

Hi I want to collect data for my program, I want to use PHP to do this(http://site.com/php?v="0.0.1"&n="Application"), how would I make the php page only work the my program, and not somebody else has the link.

How would I make sure the

Comment: Authentication and authorization.

Comment: What does this have to do with java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are various ways, but I think the one really simple is

Send a parameter some kind of token that only you and the end-script knows.

```
http://site.com/php?v=0.0.1&n=Application&token=SDGH36THGB
```

Now in your php-script, you can fetch the token parameter from request and check against something that is already saved.

```
if($_GET['token']==$myToken){
   //its my script accessing the page
}else{
   //You can show error or something
}
```

Now that was **level-1**, very simple ain't it. But what if someone comes to know about that token you're using. It can easily be exploited.

**Level-2** can be something like, there's a formula which you and the script knows for e.g. it always set toekn as todays date in yymmyyddHH format.

So now the script can check this against actual time-frame whether this is correct or not. So everytime you make a request there's a different token value depending on the current-time and then the script checks this token against the current-time frame.

Now if someone comes to know about a single-token, then also he can't replicate, since that token will not work after an hour. You can decide a more complex logic yourself.

**Level - 3 OAuth** - it's pretty difficult, but the best part is you can already find very good implementation libraries with a quick google  - https://www.google.co.in/search?q=oauth+in+php&oq=oauth+in+php&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.4208j0&sourceid=chrome&espvd=210&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8

Answer (score 0):

1. Have your users register their software, and on registration give them a user ID. Send that user ID as a get arg to the php page to identify the source of the request.
2. Have a multistep process for registering stats. Application requests a code from the server, application hashes code with a secret salt, and then application sends this salted hash back to the server along with all the usage data.

In both of these methods, you still can't tell if some user is manufacturing the requests. You're writing the client in Java, which means that no matter how complicated you make the verification process your end application will be decompilable and your methods will be reproducible.  The first solution has the advantage of isolating stats from individual users, so if a user does end up trying to screw with your system you could prune all entries from that user.